# is Spring-data-cassandra 1.4.5 compatible with Cassandra 3.0.5?

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

It seems underlying cassandra version has been upgraded to 3.0.5. Wanted to find if our current spring-data-casssandra version is compatible with new cassandra 3.0.5 version?

Any takes to point to compatibility matrix for the version check (spring-data-cassandra version to cassandra version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into dependencies for it, it looks like it won't be compatible - it's based on Cassandra 2.1 that won't work with 3.x. You need to upgrade to latest 1.5.x to be compatible with Cassandra 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Spring-data-cassandra version:1.4.5 is compatible with cassandra version: 2.1.11, based on pom definitions: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-cassandra-parent/1.4.5.RELEASE/spring-data-cassandra-parent-1.4.5.RELEASE.pom

Cassandra 3 version requires spring-data-cassnadra 1.5.x as per :
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-cassandra-parent/1.5.0.RELEASE/spring-data-cassandra-parent-1.5.0.RELEASE.pom