# Compatibility matrix for Spring-data-cassandra to cassandra version

Tags: maven, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra, maven-dependency

Please post if any pointers to check Compatibility matrix for Spring-data-cassandra version to cassandra version?

NOTE: This is a broader level question to check compatibility between DataStax's Cassandra and Spring-Data-Cassandra binary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is Spring-data-cassandra 1.4.5 compatible with Cassandra 3.0.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639577/is-spring-data-cassandra-1-4-5-compatible-with-cassandra-3-0-5)

Comment: Other question is very specific to given version compatibility, however this question is about a matrix of available to see the overall compatibility across Cassandra and spring-data-cassandra

Comment: You need to check the version of Cassandra that is used by spring-data-cassandra (I did it by checking dependencies via http://mvnrepository.com/) - usually the lower major version isn't compatible with higher major version...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Above gives answer to my other question : is Spring-data-cassandra 1.4.5 compatible with Cassandra 3.0.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/2.1.0.M2/reference/html/#new-features.1-5-0, https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/2.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#new-features.1-5-0 etc.

Try changing the version number in the URLs. It would be hard to find it all under one roof.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I tried but could not find a compatibility matrix for above dependency situation ... there exists an opportunity for a product :)

However, As @void answered, I had to crawl thru many versions/poms to find the right dependency as below:

Spring-data-cassandra version:1.4.5 is compatible with cassandra version: 2.1.11, based on pom definitions: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-cassandra-parent/1.4.5.RELEASE/spring-data-cassandra-parent-1.4.5.RELEASE.pom

Cassandra 3 version requires spring-data-cassnadra 1.5.x as per : https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-cassandra-parent/1.5.0.RELEASE/spring-data-cassandra-parent-1.5.0.RELEASE.pom